# second order diffrential equations to state space

Tags: matrices, robotics

i derived this Ordinary Difrential Equations of Motion of a self balancing robot
using lagrange mechanics the next step is to convert them to state space representaion
where with foure state variables : 
X1 = x ( position ) 
X2 = theta (inclination angle)
X3 and X3 are derivatives of X1 and X2 and to be calculated from these two ODE's

$  x ̈  (2M+ m+(2*Jw)/R^2 )+ l*m *θ ̈- l*m*θ*(θ^2 ) ̇+2μ0*x ̇=0     $   1.30

$ θ ̈(Jc+l^2*m)+( l*m)*x ̈+θ ̇(2*μ1-mgl*θ)=Tl+Tr      $    1.31

this is s picture  (first timt in the forume )

[second orders ODE's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSSnz.png)

how convert this equations to state space rep because the theta dot squared term might be a problem

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how convert this equations to state space rep because the theta dot squared term might be a problem

Comment: how convert this equations to state space rep because the theta dot squared term might be a problem